# Sybase ODBC Driver Client unable to establish connection

Tags: c#, odbc, sap-ase

I am trying to hit a remote Sybase database using ODBC. I have written a C# program with the following code

```
     try
      {
         String conString = "Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise};server=ipAddress;port=portNumber;db=databaseName;uid=strUserName;pwd=strPassword";
         con = new OdbcConnection(conString);
         con.Open();
       }
       catch (Exception exp)
        {
         con = null;

        }
```

After the connection times out ,the exception message says :-
ERROR [08001] [Sybase][ODBC Driver]Client unable to establish a connection

On Debugging the code when I hover on "con.Open()", the ServerVersion attribute  of the connection object displays the following message 'con.ServerVersion' threw an exception type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Can anybody help me in finding out the reason for this exception..?

Answer (score 0):

I would double check first that you can connect via a normal SQL client (e.g. isql, Aqua etc) on the same hostname and port.

However that looks from a quick google like a possible Sybase Adaptive Anywhere (as opposed to Enterprise) error so are you using the right driver for the type of database? They are two different products.